# How can I rename a command but still use the original command?

Tags: functions, user-commands

I have the following Vim code:

```
function! TabClose(...)
    if a:1 == ""
        tabonly
    elseif a:1 == "left"
        Tabops Close Left
    elseif a:1 == "right"
        Tabops Close Right
    else
        execute "tabclose " a:1
    endif
endfunction

command -nargs=* TabClose call TabClose("<args>")
```

I would really like to completely rebind the `tabclose` command.
So I tried the following.

```
command -nargs=* tabclose call TabClose("<args>")
```

But it did not work because `tabclose` is called in the function.
How can I name my command `tabclose` but still use the **original unmodified** `tabclose` in that function?

Comment: You can't override built-in commands; user-defined commands *must* start with a capital letter. There is no way around this I'm afraid, other than the abbreviation "correction" that Vivian posted in their answer. You can also map your custom behaviour to a key (e.g. `nnoremap TC :TabClose `), which I find quite convenient for common commands anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep your habit typing tabclose you could use:

```
cnoreabbrev tabclose TabClose
```

Or as mentioned by @Rich to avoid that the abbreviation triggers in search or as part of other commands:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> tabclose (getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == "tabclose") ? 'TabClose' : 'tabclose'
```

The `getcmdtype() == ":"` condition ensures that the abbreviation not used when using the command line to search (`/`, `?`) or non execution command line modes.

The `getcmdline() == "tabclose"` conditions ensures that the abbreviation is used only for the `:tabclose` command and not as part of some more fancy commands like `:e tabclose`

With this when you enter the command:

```
:tabclose
```

Vim will translate it to `:TabClose` when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I think this *is* close enough to what the asker requested to not need the disclaimer you added at the start. ;) It’s pretty unlikely to matter in this case, but probably worth mentioning the possible issues of this triggering in search or when not at the start of the command line, and how to fix these with `getcmdtype` and `getcmdpos`?

Comment: Thanks @Rich. I have used `getcmdline` but I'm interested to know how `getcmdpos` could be used for the same (e.g. `getcmdpos()==len('tabclose') + 1`) and what is the advantages over the `getcmdline` solution.